# MediaElement.js - how to dynamically resize videos?

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

I know how to load videos as different sizes, but I can't figure out how to change them. For instance, in my app, the video panel can be resized - I'd like to then resize the video. Problem is, there are several elements created, and I was trying to avoid resizing every child element, and just use some built-in function.

Discovered [this option](http://webtonio.com/40/) but it seemed somewhat of a crude solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="video-wrapper">
    <video width="640" height="360" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="player1">
        <source/>
    </video>
</div>
```

Via the demos/mediaelementplayer-responsive.html document that's part of the 2.9.3 download (also on github). I know inline styles are ugly but... it works! I just resize the video-wrapper as neccessary (jquery example):

```
var newHeight = 360 / 640 * newWidth;
$('#video-wrapper').css('width',newWidth);
$('#video-wrapper').css('height',newHeight+'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the default video player for YouTube & Vimeo, this often will help to "responsively" resize vids:
http://FitVidsjs.com/

I have had a friend use it with WordPress without MediaElement.js; it worked with the browser resizing, but left a black box around it.  Let me know if you can get the 2 to work well together, with a test page please. :)